# Should an NFT Marketplace be decentralized

Tags: blockchain, nft

I'm creating an nft marketplace like opensea but im getting stuck in every step of the project because of decentralization.

Because in standart e-commerce apps we use database to store data such as orders, items and users. But in decentralized apps there is no database but blockchain and blockchain is limiting me. Beacause in this situation im these questions stuck in my head.

- How can i make bid system (yeah this is possible but its harder in
  when making in smart contracts)
- How can i list items on explore page
- How can i fetch nfts that user has
- Are smart contracts secure or how can i make them secure
- In a decentralized app how can i assign users roles, delete inappropriate items from site

and many more..

So my question is should an nft marketplace be decentralized or can i use database for anything and blockchain for only nfts and transactions ? For example when user creates an nft is it correct to create an nft in blockchain and save it's tokenId in database to control everything on the database.

Comment: I am not sure, and this is just my opinion, but you probably can use something like Chromia for your decentralized DB. Please correct me if this project suitable here or not

Comment: Yes, a market could be entirely decentralized, perhaps combining with off chain protocol for handling bids. For security you should contact an auditing firm. Your question is too broad, almost anything could programmed in the blockchain, perhaps some solutions are too expensive or don't make sense.